# How to upgrade the MSI package if the previous version of the application is open at the moment

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have a quite weird scenario: I have a WPF application installed using my previous MSI (Ver 1.0), I modified my application and created new MSI (ver2.0). When I install the new MSI(Ver 2.0) and the application is not open then it updates the old msi(ver 1.0) quite smoothly.

When the application is open, update pops up the message: *"The application is running do you want to close"*. Is it possible not to pop up the message and to do a silent update instead even if an old application is open ?

Comment: The thing is upgrade would require a reboot if you don't close the running application which uses the files to be updated. *Restart Manager* as [suggested by Christopher](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11998584/572834) provides a great user experience: your is closed automatically, updated, and then restarted to the previous state.

Comment: "The application is running do you want to close" message comes up when an application doesn't respond to restart manager messages. So yes, if you implement restartmanager support the dialog will go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What tool are you using to write your MSI?   You can write a custom action to close the app or send a message telling the app to close.  Schedule this early enough so that MSI doesn't detect a running app.

You can also research the "restart manager"  functionality that exists in recent versions of Windows / Windows Installer  that provides a very nice integration to stop, upgrade and restart restoring the state of the application.  Nice stuff.

Comment: i use visual studio 2010 to create my MSI Package